# Ajax AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста, не получается вывести данные от запроса для autocomplete.
Использую этот плагин: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Код вот такой:
    $(function(){

```
function Autocomplete(url, element){
          element.autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: url,
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
              var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.name + ' <br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + suggestion.id;
              $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
            }
          });
}

  $('.autocompleteSearch input.auto').keypress(function(){
       Autocomplete($(this).attr('url'), $(this));    
 });

});
```

Проблема в выводе suggestion.name и suggestion.id

Возвращает от сервера формат JSON такого вида:

```
suggestion: {id:[3], name:[Клиника коррекции зрения]}
```

---

Вот так сделал, но все равно не прошло:

```
$(function () {
$('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url : '/institution/GetList',

            data:{
                maxRows: 12, // показать первые 12 результатов
                nameStartsWith: request.term // поисковая фраза
            },
            success: function(data){
                response($.map(data, function(item){
                    return {
                        plink: item.plink, // ссылка на страницу товара
                        label: item.title_ru // наименование товара
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // по выбору - перейти на страницу товара
        // Вы можете делать вывод результата на экран
        location.href = ui.item.plink;
        return false;
    },
    minLength: 3 // начинать поиск с трех символов
});
});
```

Обработчик:

```
public function GetList(){
        $res = array();
        if ($this->input->get('term')){
            $result = $this->institutions_model->GetInstitutions(array('like' => $this->input->get('term')));
            if (!empty($result)) {
                foreach ($result as $value) {
                    $res[] = array('id' => $value->idMedicalFacilities, 'name' => $value->MedicalFacilitiesName);
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
```

Пишет в консоли такую ошибку:

***GET http://site.ru/user/null?query=%D0%BA 404 (Not Found)***

Comment: Оффтоп. А чем он принципиально лучше, чем родной плагин [
Autocomplete jQuery UI][1]? Более подробная документация или скрытые возможности?

   [1]:http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример для Autocomplete jQuery UI, чтобы можно было получить Name записи и Id по выбору из списка. Спасибо

Comment: Вот такой пример у меня не работает, т-е не делает alert и ничего не отображает на странице:
$(function(){

function Autocomplete(url, element){
 
element.autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: url,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        //$( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
       alert(ui.item.id);
        return false;
      }
    })
}

  $('.autocompleteSearch input.auto').keypress(function(){
       Autocomplete($(this).attr('url'), $(this));    
 });

});

Comment: @Deonis, у вас должно кармы хватать чтобы забрасывать в комментарий...

@junart если ваш "ответ" не дает ответ, а вы хотите дополнить вопрос - дополняйте вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

*В комментарий не поместилось, посему пишу ответом*

> Приведите пожалуйста пример

На официальом сайте, примеров море. Если и того мало, то могу показать свой, взятый из реального проекта - поиск по группе товаров. (*Лишнее убрал, серверную честь схематизировал, основные настройки у меня находятся в $.ajaxSetup()*)

**JS**

```
$('#search_field').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            data:{
                maxRows: 12, // показать первые 12 результатов
                nameStartsWith: request.term // поисковая фраза
            },
            success: function(data){
                response($.map(data, function(item){
                    return {
                        plink: item.plink, // ссылка на страницу товара
                        label: item.title_ru // наименование товара
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // по выбору - перейти на страницу товара
        // Вы можете делать вывод результата на экран
        location.href = ui.item.plink;
        return false;
    },
    minLength: 3 // начинать поиск с трех символов
});
```

**PHP**

```
// Ищем в БД по ключевому слову $_POST['nameStartsWith']
// Если что-то находим, то формируем ответ:
$response = array(); 
while($row = $res->fetch()){
    $response[] = array(
        'title_ru' => $row['title_ru'],
        'plink' => itemPath($row['item_id']) // тут у меня функция формирует ссылку
        /* добавлять можно всё, что угодно. Хоть маму с папой впихнуть ;) */
    );
}
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

P.S. Опции ajax за кадром - **type: 'POST'**, **dataType: 'json'**, **url: '/*тут ваш*/'**, всякие **beforeSend, complete, error** - на ваше усмотрение. Все, что вам остается сделать - это подключить виджет [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/download/) и указать свой селектор поискового поля формы.

Comment: Спасибо. Только сейчас при выборе подсвеченного результата, в поле вставляет ID записи а не название. Нужно наоборот, чтобы в скрытое поле добавлялось ID выбранной записи, а в input название выбранного элемента.